# Android Studio change TextView fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have created an activity in activities folder and one fragment in fragments folder. Look how my fragment builds: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIt9W.png

Some else tried like me by doing this [Android : Update Tab Layout(fragments) textviews from an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837643/android-update-tab-layoutfragments-textviews-from-an-activity), but I don't understand what was the solution.

How can I send data like string from activity to this fragment and I want it in tab2 (like in picture)?

I try many ways and I didn't find solution

From my activity

```java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And from Fragment

```java
String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
```

does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend an alternative solution - using a 3rd party library called [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It's quite easy to use and it's very useful for different scenarios.
Create a custom event, something like this:

```
public class MyEvent {
private String text;

public MyEvent(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text= text;
}
```

And simply in your Activity, post this event with the text you wish to send to the fragment:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvent(yourTextString);
```

Now simply register the eventBus in `onCreate` of your Fragment:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And create a method that listens for the event like this:

```
@Subscribe
public void onMyEvent(MyEvent myEvent){
    String text = myEvent.getText();
    //Now you can do whatever you wish with this text
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer,
I need to add this library ?
if yes how and where put it?

Comment: You do need to add this library. Follow their guide on how to get started provided in the link.

Comment: Nice! This library will fix many of your problems :) Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with the solution :)

Comment: Thanks, all work great, Now if i want to add every event the string to ListView. it's right to do like this:

        List<cources> orderList;
        orderList = new ArrayList<cources>();
        cources lst = new cources();
        lst.name = text; //this text from event
        orderList.add(lst);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(orderList, context);
        listOrder.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Yes, ok. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I try this the text does not add to list and the list does open new row.
Nothing happened i check if the text was send with this:
        String text = event.getText();
        name.setText(text); //name is TextView 
and yes the text was send but listview does not updated

do you have Facebook,skype,whatsapp easy way to spoke?

Comment: You must understand bro that nobody here is going to guide you through your whole app for **free**. I answered your original question. As for this new one, you probably need to add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or how else would the listview know that you've added some items to the list?

Comment: I am not want that people help me with all my app, only in few things that i am now sure or know.
about adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() i have java class named ListAdapter with list_adapter.xml this work good in Activity
in fragment it need to be different?

Comment: You need to do it on an `instance` of the class ListAdapter, not the class itself. For example, where are you instantiating that class? `ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter();` Add when the text changes `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Look i add some answer to my self post i add the costume adapter

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Context context;
List<cources> valueList;

public ListAdapter(List<cources> listValue, Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.valueList = listValue;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return this.valueList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return this.valueList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewItem viewItem = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        viewItem = new ViewItem();
        LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_view, null);

        viewItem.txtNamePlanche = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tx_name_planche);
        viewItem.txtPriceBaget = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tx_price_baget);
        viewItem.txtPricePlate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tx_price_plate);
        convertView.setTag(viewItem);
    }
    else
    {
        viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewItem.txtNamePlanche.setText(valueList.get(position).name);
    viewItem.txtPriceBaget.setText(valueList.get(position).price_baget);
    viewItem.txtPricePlate.setText(valueList.get(position).price_plate);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

and viewitem

```
class ViewItem
{
TextView txtNamePlanche;
TextView txtPricePlate;
TextView txtPriceBaget;
}
```